# Why does it not matter that the material wave equation is not invariant under the Galilean transformation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, galilean-relativity

I have a doubt, when the Galileo transformations are applied to the electromagnetic wave equation, more terms appear and to solve it the Lorentz transforms are used, however, what does not comply with the Galileo transformations is the general wave equation.

Comment: Hint: The material itself constitutes a preferred frame.